# How to get an element of an array inside another array?

Tags: arrays, swift

So the only way i can think of achieving this is by putting the array inside mainArray into a variable and then indexing that. Is there an easier way?

```
  mainArray          = [ 3400, "Overwatch", [UIButton(), UIButton()]] // Some buttons already made
  currentButtonArray = mainArray[mainArray.count - 1] as! NSArray

    for i in 0..<currentButtonArray.count {
        buttonArray.append( currentButtonArray[i] as! UIButton)
    }
```

Comment: This is likely an inappropriate data structure – what exactly are you using this array for?

Comment: @Hamish My goal is every now and then i would check the main array if it added buttons (Which it will), and disable userInteraction for those newly added buttons (After being pressed) by looping through the buttonArray

Comment: But what does the contents of `mainArray` represent? Integers, Strings and `[UIButton]`s aren't related.

Comment: @Hamish imagine going through a park and every sign you read you want to add it to your bag ("String") and every now and then you get to cross roads and you have to choose a button ("Buttons"). Integers not really using them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is **one** array containing only `UIButton` instances, just `filter` it.

```
let mainArray : [Any] = [3400, "Overwatch", [UIButton(), UIButton()]]
if let buttonArray = mainArray.filter({$0 is [UIButton]}).first as? [UIButton] {
  print(buttonArray)
}
```

or

```
let buttonArray = Array(mainArray.flatMap{$0 as? [UIButton]}.joined())
```

The second approach returns a non-optional empty array if there is no array of `UIButton` in `mainArray`

Comment: Or you could do `mainArray.flatMap({$0 as? [UIButton]}).first` ;) If there's more than one array, you could do a `.lazy.flatMap` in order to ensure that it stops iterating upon finding the first `[UIButton]`.

Comment: There will be more than one array of buttons. Will i take the same approach?

Comment: What result do you expect? The result of the `flatMap` solution is one array containing all buttons. The `filter` solution returns only the first array.

Answer (score 1):

If the subarray is of all one type, you can append all in one go:

```
var buttonArray = [UIButton]()
let mainArray:[Any] = [3400, "Overwatch", [UIButton(), UIButton()]] // Some buttons already made
if let currentButtonArray = mainArray.last as? [UIButton] {
   buttonArray.append(contentsOf: currentButtonArray)
}
```

Or you could simply write:

```
guard let currentButtonArray = mainArray.last as? [UIButton] else {
    // do something e.g. return or break
    fatalError()
}
// do stuff with array e.g. currentButtonArray.count
```

If you didn't know the position in the array of the nested UIButton array or if there were multiple nested button arrays then this would work:

```
let buttonArray = mainArray.reduce([UIButton]()){ (array, element) in if let bArray = element as? [UIButton] {
        return array + bArray
    }
    else {
         return array
    }
}
```

Note: this is Swift 3 code.